# ElasticSearch cardinality aggregation with multiple query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a document with merchant and item. my document will look liken

```
{
  "merchant": "M1",
  "item": "I1"
}
```

For the given list of merchant names, I want to get number of unique items on each merchant.

I was able to get number of unique items on a given merchant by following query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "merchant": "M1"
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "count_unique_items": {
            "cardinality": {
                "field": "I1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to expand this query so instead of 1 merchant, I can do search for N merchants with one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use terms query to match multiple merchants and use multilevel aggregation to find unique count per merchant. So create a terms aggregation for merchant and then add cardinality aggregation as sub aggregation to the terms aggregation. Query will look like below:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "merchant": [
        "M1",
        "M2"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "merchent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "merchant"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "item_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "item"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, i got error ""request does not support [size]". After removing size I got error ""request does not support [aggs]"

Comment: Opps I wrote `I1` instead of `item`. Corrected that. Also add `.keyword` to the field names if their data type is not keyword. Eg. `item.keyword`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by @Opster ES Ninja Nishant, you need to use multilevel aggregation.

Adding a working example with index data,search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "merchant": "M3",
  "item": ["I3","I2"]
}
{
  "merchant": "M2",
  "item": ["I2","I2"]
}
{
  "merchant": "M1",
  "item": "I1"
}
```

**Search Query:**

**To count the unique number of `item` for a given `merchant`, in the cardinality aggregation instead of `I1`, you should use the `item` field**

```
{
  "size":0,
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "merchant.keyword": [
        "M1",
        "M2",
        "M3"
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "merchent": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "merchant.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "item_count": {
          "cardinality": {
            "field": "item.keyword"       <-- note this
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"aggregations": {
    "merchent": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "M1",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "item_count": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "M2",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "item_count": {
            "value": 1
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "M3",
          "doc_count": 1,
          "item_count": {
            "value": 2
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: @Kazuki did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)