# How to get the count of unique values of a field, using logstash filter plugin?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

**I am trying to get the count of unique values of a field, using the logstash filter plugin** in such a way that :

For Example: Documents contained in the index (let's say `index1`) are:

```
{
    "city": "agra",
    "id": 1
}
{
    "city": "kolkata",
    "id": 2
}
{
    "city": "agra",
    "id": 1
}
{
    "city": "agra",
    "id": 2
}
{
    "city": "agra",
    "id": 3
}
```

Let's say the incoming document is

```
{
    "city": "agra",
    "id": 5
}
```

Now, since the incoming document, have `city=agra`, so

**I want to get the count of unique values of `id` field for `agra` city.
Once I get the count, I need to check the value of the count. If the value of count is  `>=3` , then a new field `id_count` should be added to the document.**

So, since `agra` contains 3 unique ids in the already indexed documents, which are 1, 2, 3 (whose count == 3), the new field must be added to the documents.

I tried to do it using the below logstash config, but I was not able to get my required result :

```
input {
  tcp {
    port => 3501
  }
}

filter {
  aggregate {
      task_id => "%{id}"
      code => "map['id_count'] ||= 0; map['id_count'] += 1;"
    }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9900"
    index => "index2"
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me resolve this issue ?

And is there any way to add a query with aggregation in the Elasticsearch filter plugin query template?

Comment: You can do a [cardinality](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) query using an elasticsearch filter, but do you want to do that, or do you want to use an aggregate filter?

Comment: @Badger can I use a combination of a search query like `match` query for searching for `city=agra`, and based on the search response do a cardinality aggregation to get the count of unique ids ? Is this combination possible in the query template of Elasticsearch filter plugin ?

Comment: Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64870826/elasticsearch-cardinality-aggregation-with-multiple-query) answer. It should work in an elasticsearch filter plugin.